# Search for all values in a python dictonary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I'm doing a parser in python. But i don't know how to search all the way down in the dictionary structure.

Lets say i want to be able to grab all values that contains None.

```
{data01: 'full', data02:'None', data03:'high', data04:'None'}
```

I have tried with the following:

```
if None in inputfromjson.values():
    excludekey
```

Comment: Maybe yaml.dump has a "ignore:None"

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have nested dictionaries. So i need to find "None" lower down in the structure. And also when i find the Value None i want it to be excluded.

Comment: Found howto remove Null. sys.stdout.write(yaml.dump(resources).replace("null", ""))

Comment: It removes the value Null. But the key is still present. I need to find a way to not present the key as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: a = {'data01': 'full', 'data02': None, 'data03': 'high', 'data04': None}                                                                         

In [2]: if None in a.values(): 
   ...:     print(True) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                  
True
```

Seems fine just make the dictionary definition right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get each key, where the value is none, simply iterate over the dict:

```
a = {'data01': 'full', 'data02': None, 'data03': 'high', 'data04': None}  
for key in a:
  if a[key] is None:
     print(key)
```

Note that for the check for `None` it is better to use the `is` instead of the `==` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

By this way,you can figure out all the keys which is None.

```
a = {'data01': 'full', 'data02': None, 'data03': 'high', 'data04': None}
for key,value in a.items():
    if value == None:
        print(key)
```

a.items() is a container, which returns a tuple, containing key and its corresponding value.